# Inserting into a temp table multiple counts for same row

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a temp table and for the table have it display: count of results yearly | count weekly | count daily all in the same row.

so the first row should look like.

8 | 3 | 0 so this is for all recorded added in the year, the week, the day

Here is my php code to accomplish this but it is not letting me select the counts and insert them into the table.

```
// Create temporary table
$sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_overview(
company varchar(50),
countYearly int,
countWeekly int,
countDaily int    
)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo "Failed first";    
}

// Insert into temp table
$sql = "INSERT INTO temp_overview(countYearly, countWeekly, countDaily)
SELECT
    (SELECT count(*) FROM client_companies WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR(CURDATE())) AS companyCountY,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM client_companies WHERE DATE(date_added) >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))) AS companyCountW,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM client_companies WHERE DAY(date_added) = DAY(CURDATE())) AS companyCountD
FROM
    client_companies";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo "Failed second";   
}
```

It is failing in the second sql statement how can I get the selected counts to be added to a single row in the temp table?

Comment: Is this `mysql` or `sql-server`? They are not the same thing.

Comment: mysql sorry i didnt see i tagged that.

Comment: Whats your error message?

Comment: Well on my test echo its giving failed second. It has to do with that query. Here is the mysql error: #1054 - Unknown column 'countWeekly' in 'field list'

Comment: Nevermind i wasnt using the correct column name. Now though its giving me 8 results? it should only give me one result set correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your second sql to be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO temp_overview(countYearly, countWeekly, countDaily) VALUES (
(SELECT count(*) FROM client_companies WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR(CURDATE())),
(SELECT count(*) FROM client_companies WHERE DATE(date_added) >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))),
(SELECT count(*) FROM client_companies WHERE DAY(date_added) = DAY(CURDATE()))
)
```

Comment: Wow... I cannot believe I had left out the values keyword. This works what a dumb mistake i made. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Schema

```
create table thing9
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    theDate date not null
);
truncate table thing9;
insert thing9(theDate) values ('2015-11-09'),('2015-11-05'),('2015-10-20'),('2015-10-19'),
('2015-08-20'),('2015-01-20'),('2014-12-20'),('2014-07-20');
-- 8 rows
```

### Query

```
SELECT
    (select count(*) from thing9 where DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)<=theDate) as withinWeek,
    (select count(*) from thing9 where DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)<=theDate) as withinMonth,
    (select count(*) from thing9 where DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)<=theDate) as withinYear;

+------------+-------------+------------+
| withinWeek | withinMonth | withinYear |
+------------+-------------+------------+
|          1 |           4 |          7 |
+------------+-------------+------------+
```

See the manual page on [Mysql Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Use of `interval` is very cool.

Look into `date_add`, `date_sub`, and `datediff`, in general.

Comment: Actually this is a way i havent thought of this might work better for me.